# error with django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: on Django 2.2.5

Tags: django

I know that this question has been asked before and I went through every possible answers given, and it still does not make it for me! I am running django 2.2.5 and python 3.7 on PyCharm.

My manage.py seems to be working fine. The issue is coming from my admin file, I believe I know but I do not know where the issue could be. I ran django-admin check in terminal, which also give me an error. My only file that raises an error is my admin.py, but I cannot understand why. I copied my admin.py file as well as the errors that I get when I write the commands on the terminal

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from inventory1.templates.models import *

@admin.register(Item)
class ViewAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    exclude= ('id',)
```

And when I execute it, I get the error:

```
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Now, I am sure this is related too. When I try `django-admin check`, I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting TEMPLATES, but settings are not configured.
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

From previous questions, this issue was coming from an issue with settings in the manage.py file. I am confident that this one is correct, I still add it just in case:

```py
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "inventory_management.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What happens if you do `./manage.py check --settings=inventory_management.settings`

Comment: And what exactly are you running when you get the first error? You say "When I execute it" but you can't execute an admin.py file since that requires django to be setup first.

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: with this command, I get " RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".  Should I still show you  the full traceback, it's huge?

Comment: @LeLionJaune add the full traceback.

Comment: I meant of when i tryed to run it on Pycharm, I got so caught in this problem that i didn't even realized that i didnt make any sense to do that!

Comment: would you have an advice on how I could include the full traceback here? or is there a specific part that is most important? the entired traceback largely exceed the limit so it wont let me edit my post.

Comment: The RecursionError is an improvement, you're probably importing something in your models that is importing your models itself. It's strange your models file is in the templates directory (it shouldn't) and you shouldn't import * but import the classes you need explicitly.

Comment: If that's the entire `admin.py` file, then the problem could be from either `from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin` or `from inventory1.templates.models import *`. The traceback should indicate where the problem is. If you can't show the traceback, then experiment with disabling one of those imports to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: The important parts of the stack trace are the lines in files belonging to your project. It's important to learn to read a stack trace, find the lines in your own files that cause the error and debug from there.

Comment: Note to run in PyCharm: in your configuration, the only thing you need to set is the Environment variables settings: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=inventory_management.settings` and the python interpreter (to the one in your virtualenv). PyCharm uses `manage.py runserver` so that should work. I never user `django-admin` myself, only manage.py.

Comment: alright, here is what I did, I renamed the * with the actual class, I moved model.py file out of templates, so I edited the import on admin.py and modify INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. I ran /manage.py runserver and the error that I get is: "raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."

Comment: Thank you for the advices, I can definitely get better at debugging by taking more time studying the traceback. And I have seen on another post to set the environment variable this way on Pycharm, so already had it set. for the interpreter, i use "Project Default(python 3.7) located at /usr/local/bin/python. Could this the error right there?

Comment: As Dirk said, the problem is probably a circular import in your `models.py`. We can’t offer any more help than that because you haven’t posted the traceback or models.py.